# Flutter: DIfference if I run the app from xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter

I'm new to flutter, after native coding Android and ios, in Android Studio and XCode.

In flutter, I'm writing the code in Android Studio, and testing from there. This all works well for android devices. When I test on ios devices, if I run the app from android studio onto my iphone, it takes age to build. If however, I open the runner project in xcode, and run it from there, it works fine. What I am asking is, does it make any difference if I test my ios device by running the project from xcode or not?

Thanks for the basic question, I'm new to flutter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it odd that it builds so much more quickly directly from Xcode, as all the other two IDEs are doing are building with Xcode via terminal commands, but to answer your question, the output to the device/emulator will be the same either way.

Comment: Thanks. I agree, its weird. I just get Running Xcode build... in the Android Studio console for literally ages...

Comment: You will lose out on one of Flutter's best features though: hot reload/restart.

Comment: Right, I am seeing that the first build takes long. Then using hot reload/restart is instant. Are there any times I need to do a fresh build, or is hot reload/restart always sufficient? Thanks a lot.

Comment: They should always be sufficient. In general, use reload when it is mostly UI changes and restart for larger logic changes outside of build methods, pubspec.yaml changes, etc. You'll learn what requires reload as you use it.